# rails joins polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, polymorphic-associations

I have a ploymorphic association named `Notifiable` in a model named `Notifiaction`:

```
module Notifiable
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      has_many :notifications, :as => :notifiable, :inverse_of => :notifiable, :dependent => :destroy
    end
  end
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Notifiable
end

class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Notifiable
end

class Notification
  belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :bill, foreign_key: 'notifiable_id', conditions: "notifiable_type = 'Bill'"
  belongs_to :balance, foreign_key: 'notifiable_id', conditions: "notifiable_type = 'Balance'"
end
```

when I try to join notification with notifiable (`Notification.joins{notifiable}` - it's squeel, active record code will have the same result) I get the error: `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :notifiable`

I've seen some posts about this exception but none of them was exactly my case when I try to just join the tables. Is it possible? what am I missing

Comment: Can you please show your correct declarations? I assume you really mean `class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base`, etc?

Comment: I think you can't do join on the association on polymorphic type. It should be either: `Notification.joins(:bill)` or `Notification.joins(:balance)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can eager load both polymorphic associations by using includes:

```
Notification.where(whatever: "condition").includes(:notifiable)
```

Considering both Bill and Balance results match the query result, the include should preload both models in the query result. ie:

```
Notification.where(whatever: "condition").includes(:notifiable).map(&:notifiable)
# => [Bill, Balance, etc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the bill and balance associations declared, you Can join individual associations and Do a Union on them.

Something like

```
scope :billiables_for_account, ->(account) do
  union_scope(joins(:bill).where(bills: {account: account}),
      joins(:balance).where(bills: {account: account}))
end
```