# Rails: polymorphic associations, find commented on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I've implemented polymorphic comments on my Rails app using [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations).

So I have:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I want to index all comments and join them with the places they comment on, but I have no idea on how to achieve this.

In my `comments_controller.rb` I have:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
end
```

And in my comments `index.html.erb` I can access:

```
<%= comment.commentable_type %>
<%= comment.commentable_id %>
```

But how do I access the actual attributes of what the comments are on, example: `<%= comment.place.name %>`?

I believe it is related to this answer but I don't know how: [rails joins polymorphic association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390384/rails-joins-polymorphic-association)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the commentable object with just

```
comment.commentable
```

The only thing to watch out for here is that it assumes that all your commentables have the method you call on them, such as `name`.

```
comment.commentable.name
```

You will want to preload these in your controller to avoid an N+1 as well.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.includes(:commentable).all
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Showing how it avoids the N+1:
Without `t.includes(:commentable).all` it does a `SELECT` for each place that has a comment. With `t.includes(:commentable).all` it does a single `SELECT` with a `WHERE "places"."id" IN (7, 9)`.

Answer (score 0):

**mccalljt answer's above is much better**

Believe I've got it:

Added to `comment.rb`:

```
belongs_to :place, foreign_key: 'commentable_id'
```

Added to `comments_controller.rb`:

```
@comments = Comment.where(commentable_type: "Place").joins(:place)
```

Though this is not reusable when there are more associations, but I could change it to:

```
@place_comments = Comment.where(commentable_type: "Place").joins(:place)
@other_comments = Comment.where(commentable_type: "Other").joins(:other)
```